# MS SQL Ignore existing data on ALTER TABLE CHECK

Tags: sql-server

I am working on an MS SQL script where I would like to create a table, add some test data and add a check constraint.

#### 1. Create table

```
CREATE TABLE PricingTable (
    PrijsId INT IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT pk_prijsid PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductCode varchar(5) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_pricingtable_productcode FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product(ProductCode),
    StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    EndDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Price FLOAT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT check_einddatum_prijs CHECK (Einddatum > StartDatum)
```

)

#### 2. Add test data

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Prijstabel
        ( ProductCode , StartDate , EndDate , Price)
VALUES  
( 'OB' , CAST('01/01/2016' AS DATETIME) , CAST('12/31/2016' AS DATETIME) , 15.0 ),
( 'KVT' , CAST('01/01/2016' AS DATETIME) , CAST('12/31/2016' AS DATETIME) , 10.0 );
```

#### 3. Add check constraint on start date after entering test data

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Prijstabel ADD CONSTRAINT check_startdatum_prijs CHECK (StartDatum >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

#### Error message

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "check_startdatum_prijs". The conflict occurred in database "Bezorgdienst", table "dbo.Prijstabel", column 'StartDatum'.
```

I would like to fill the database with some test data, where the start date is before the current date.
How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE foo NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

Run this statement to disable check constraints. Replace"foo" with your table name.

Comment: Where should I put this statement? I have put it before and after every statement in the script but got the same error every time.

Comment: Run it once and then try inserting data